# experimenting Color Manipulation in openlayers 6 fails with tileSource.getTileGridForProjection is not a function

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-6

Using openlayers 6.2.1, i am trying to change pixel color of tiles from an xyz source (like Color Manipulation [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/color-manipulation.html)),

I define first a XYZ source :

```
const xyz = new XYZ({
    url: 'https://mbenzekri.github.io/frcommunes/fr/communes/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    maxZoom: 12,
    minZoom: 5
})
```

then a RasterSource to manipulate colors

```
const rastersource= new Raster({
    sources: [ xyz ],
    operation: function (pixels, data) { 
        pixels[0] = pixels[0] 
        pixels[1] = pixels[1] 
        pixels[2] = pixels[2] 
    }
})
```

then an ImageLayer :

```
const imagelayer = new ImageLayer({
    source: rastersource
})
```

adding this layer in my map over an OSM layer object fails with message at rendering time :

```
TileLayer.js:160 Uncaught TypeError: tileSource.getTileGridForProjection is not a function
    at CanvasTileLayerRenderer.renderFrame (TileLayer.js:160)
    at TileLayer.Layer.render (Layer.js:216)
    at CompositeMapRenderer.renderFrame (Composite.js:112)
    at Map.PluggableMap.renderFrame_ (PluggableMap.js:1265)
    at Map.<anonymous> (PluggableMap.js:186)
```

replacing imagelayer by a simple TileLayer with the same xyz source works fine (source code line index.js:37).

```
const tilelayer = new TileLayer({
    source: xyz
})
```

am i doing something wrong, missing some configurations ?

thanks in advance for your help or interest

full code is  [here](https://github.com/mbenzekri/frcommunes) (simple example 50 lines)

the bug free version is testable at [github page](https://mbenzekri.github.io/frcommunes/dist/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import is wrong.

```
import ImageLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
```

should be

```
import ImageLayer from 'ol/layer/Image';
```